# In Vue.js, why isn't my computed property working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In the following code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    myMessage: function() {
      return "hello";
    }
  },
  data: {
    message: this.myMessage
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.log(this.myMessage);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hk49eL38/

if I replace:

`this.myMessage` with a string (eg "Hello world"), it renders correctly.

But when I use `this.myMessage`, no text is rendered.

Why is this?

Comment: Think of it like this: `data` is where you store you initial values, `computed` is like the name says, results of some computation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use the computed property as the initial value of the `message` data property.

When the `data` function is called internally by Vue, the computed properties haven't been evaluated yet, this is done very early, before the `created` hook.

If you try to log the value of the computed property in the `beforeCreated` hook (the first life-cycle hook) instead of the `mounted` as in your example, you will see that it is `undefined`.

See the [component life-cycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks):

[image]

(*) Diagram cropped for brevity

Computed properties are evaluated in the **"Init injections & reactivity"** step in the above diagram.

Computed property values cannot be used as the initial value of a property of `data`, and normally they depend on `data` property values and other external and reactive values (e.g. Vuex getters, Vue router parameters, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `this` before writing `myMessage`, as VueJS doesn't work like that. It already considers everything in `this` context. You should do it like this:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ myMessage }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Agree, rendering `{{ myMessage }}` will work, but the real problem is that the OP is trying to use the computed property as the initial value of a `data` property and this doesn't work due the component life-cycle.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the value of **myMesssage** to **message** when component is mounted.

```
mounted: function() {
    this.message = this.myMessage
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to change the data message in the computed my message